# DateFormat conversion problem in java?

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

my input String is : 2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z

output pattern is like:

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE. MMM. d. yyyy");
```

i convert this like this:

```
formatter1.format(new Date("2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z"));//illegalArgumentException here the string "2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z"
```

ouput should be like this: Thu. Mar. 24. 2010 idea

but i get a **illegalArgumentException**. Dont know why? any idea??

stacktrace message is:

```
04-08 19:50:28.326: WARN/System.err(306): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-08 19:50:28.345: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:447)
04-08 19:50:28.355: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:157)
04-08 19:50:28.366: WARN/System.err(306):     at com.example.brown.Bru_Tube$SelectDataTask.doInBackground(Bru_Tube.java:222)
04-08 19:50:28.366: WARN/System.err(306):     at com.example.brown.Bru_Tube$SelectDataTask.doInBackground(Bru_Tube.java:1)
04-08 19:50:28.405: WARN/System.err(306):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-08 19:50:28.415: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-08 19:50:28.415: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-08 19:50:28.446: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-08 19:50:28.456: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-08 19:50:28.466: WARN/System.err(306):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: IllegalArgumentException where? I'd post the stack trace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
new Date("2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z")
```

Apparently it doesn't accept dates/times in that format.

You shouldn't be using that constructor anyway - create an appropriate formatter to parse that particular format, and then parse it with that.

Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to start with, and avoid using `DateFormat` completely. I don't know if you can use Joda Time from Android, mind you... and it's fairly large.

EDIT: To spell it out explicitly:

```
String inputText = "2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z";
// "Z" appears not to be supported for some reason.
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE. MMM. d. yyyy");
Date parsed = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);

// Output is Wed. Mar. 24 2010 on my box
```

Comment: joda time is not convenient with android. i think so.can we have any other way in java? i mean can we mention the date and time input and output format.and then i convert it.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat has a pattern on its JavaDoc that matches this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: As Jon Skeet says use a SimpleDateFormat to parse the date, similar to how you already use it to format the date.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is the way to go

Comment: how to use that? i cant get u people. plz elobrate... :(

Comment: @androidbase: Which bit of it don't you understand? Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` to create an appropriate date format, then call `format.parse("2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z")` to get a `Date`.

Comment: @OMG Unicorns: Looks like the Z time zone format doesn't support the literal "Z" bizarrely enough. I've set it explicitly...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I was wondering about that, as I didn't see it mentioned on the `SimpleDateFormat` page.  I guess I should have tested it.  P.S. OMG Unicorns is a parody name, but I can't change it again until May 1st... stupid 30 day rule... *grumble*

Answer (score 0):

## `'Z'` is not the same as `Z`

`'Z'` is just a character literal whereas `Z` is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Therefore, ***do not use `'Z'` in pattern*** for parsing/formatting.

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. The Date-Time string, `2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z` conforms to ISO 8601 standards.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z");

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE. MMM. d. uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed. Mar. 24. 2010
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6Zq04s)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdfInput.parse("2010-03-24T17:28:50.000Z");

        // Custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE. MMM. d. uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed. Mar. 24. 0003
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4yxWq3)

**Note:** Always use `Locale` with `DateTimeFormatter` and `SimpleDateFormat` as these are `Locale`-sensitive types.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>