# Conversion of Date

Tags: java, android, date, date-formatting, date-parsing

I am getting date in two different formats.
1) `2012-01-05`
2) `05/01/2012`
But I want this to be in the below format. `"5 Jan 2011"`

Now I'm having `String d1="2012-01-05"` and `String d2="2012-01-05".`

Comment: Just refer [this](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) and you will get it.

Comment: Just search in google about simpledateformat

Comment: It is not the exactly what you want but 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600581/dateformat-conversion-problem-in-java/2600648#2600648 might help you!

Comment: @Selvin Help others so in future someone help you....

Comment: @yshak dont depressed ..i will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");  
String now = formatter.format(new Date());
```

this u want right...

or

```
String oldString = "2009-12 Dec";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").parse(oldString)); // Yes, month name is ignored but we don't need this.
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(newString); // 31-DEC-2009
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

You need a `DateTimeFormatter` with two optional patterns for parsing your date-time strings into instances of `LocalDate`. Then, you need a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `LocalDate` instances into the desired pattern.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[uuuu-MM-dd][dd/MM/uuuu]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Stream.of(
                "2012-01-05",
                "05/01/2012"
            )
            .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, parser))
            .map(d -> d.format(formatter))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
5 Jan 2012
5 Jan 2012
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HOYpro)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)

You have to determine, which format is used and than create a appropriate pattern.

After parsing the date, you can format it with another pattern, if you need a String:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");  
String now = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should retrieve the date in the format you want. Simple few lines.

```
            String pattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

            System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String d1 = "2012-01-05";
String d2 = "05/01/2012";
SimpleDateFormat curFormater1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat curFormater2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dateObj1 = null;

Date dateObj2 = null;
try {
    dateObj1 = curFormater.parse(d1);
    dateObj2 = curFormater.parse(d2);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String date_new1 = formatter.format(d1);
String date_new2 = formatter.format(d2);
```

try this code it will help you so solve your problem