# Convert date from m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion of Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742830/conversion-of-date)
>   [How to convert date from m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404824/how-to-convert-date-from-m-d-yy-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

I get the date in a String as: 5/1/12.
I need to convert it to 05/01/2012.
Please suggest.

I used the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

d_date = dateFormat.parse("5/1/12"); 

strDate = dateFormat.format(d_date);

Result:
05/01/0012
```

Expected Result:
05/01/2012

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: removed `javaScript` tag. It's wise to read comments when your question is closed to learn from mistakes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404824/how-to-convert-date-from-m-d-yy-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Why would you tag Javascript and Java? They're two completely different things.

Comment: *Please* don't re-post questions. Fix the original post, and try to get it re-opened.

Comment: -1 You have repeated the same question once again even though the previous one had already been closed. This is considered to be the abuse of the community on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java (from the previous closed question)

Comment: It says marked as duplicate but even original is removed

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("5/1/12");

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.format(date);
```

The following links should prove helpful for more complicated tasks:

[Oracle SimpleDateFormat Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[Example code](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/parsedate.html)

Comment: Please review the links attached to your answer, They are not working